# How do I extract the TCP data packet from Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, computer-forensics

This is a [CTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag#Computer_security) challenge (a set of online information security challenges) and I have become stuck.

I noticed in the conversation one person asks for the other person to send the salted password file.

[image]

I wanted to grab that data, so I right clicked it and copied as printable text:

[image]

```
Salted__ð£s¯H+^1Y®ê-ié«æ×¹½¦þFÐö}×Gþ|vÎ
```

At this point, I think I have the salted password, so I save it to *file.des3*.

In the conversation, the dialog is as follows:

> Hey, how do you decrypt this file again?
> You're serious?
> Yeah, I'm serious
> *sigh* **openssl des3 -d -salt -in file.des3 -out file.txt -k supersecretpassword123**

So I figured this is basically telling me how to do it. So I run the same command:

```
rasp4@server:/ctf$ openssl des3 -d -salt -in file.des3 -out file.txt -k supersecretpassword123
```

The following output appears:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
139871006373184:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:599:
```

I look at the contents of file.txt and see this:

```
à@ %eõý#Äu´;RTÉÒ…²eèmkúì Øß”Êrâês¸qEG
```

I'm lost on what to do at this point. What am I supposed to do with that output? Why did I get an error from running the same command as the conversation did? My intuition is telling me something didn't copy from the data on Wireshark properly.

Comment: Hi Jeff. The problem with the latest edit is that the question now launches into detail without setting out the appropriate context. In the sentence "I noticed in the conversation one person asks for the other person", what conversation is "the conversation", and who the people are, has not been explained. Can you add some introductory material to improve upon this? Questions here are intended for a future audience far into the future, so it is great if they can be made as readable as possible.

Comment: Yo I know this is already answered and it worked for me too. What I'm more upset about is the question giving a whole writeup to the ctf challenge, all of this doesn't matter to the problem at hand and only spoilers some one if they aren't that far in the challenge yet.

Comment: @TD3V: it's fair feedback. Could you make a post about that [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)? I don't know how that might be solved, but it is not a theme I have considered before.

Comment: Are questions about how to use [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What is "the conversation"? What does it refer to?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen: I think Wireshark qualifies as "programmers' tools" and thus would on-topic.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427137/question-about-a-task-in-a-ctf-challenge-gives-the-write-up-to-the-challenge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on "Data: 53616..." in the Frame Details window so that you can select "Export Packet Bytes..." Export to a file named "file.des3" then try the decryption command again. Your intuition is right in saying that "something didn't copy from the data on Wireshark properly," because the "Copy" feature tends to add a lot of extra bytes to the data, which simply obfuscates that original hash.